# Counting how many comma seperated strings in an input

Tags: javascript, jquery

How do I display the number of comma seperated data in a input box?

Example:
Input box: 2015-01-01, 2015-01-02, 2015-01-03
I want the output to another box saying 3 because there are 3 dates selected.

I tried something like:

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').val().split(",");
for (i=0; i < vacDays.length; i++) {
    $('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays[i]);
}
```

But this only displays the last date for some reason?

I also tried:

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').split(",");
$('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays);
```

but this doesn't do anything for me.

Lastly I tried:

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').length;
$('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays);
```

But this only outputs 1.

Any help would be great. Thanks again!

Comment: if you want to know just number of comma then  $('#vacationDays').val().split(",").length will give you number of comma present in the value

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This would display the number of comma separated strings

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').val().split(",").length;
 $('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays);
```

Comment: THANK YOU!! WORKED PERFECTLY! I was on the right track I guess :p

Comment: @MartinSmith Yeah you were close... you tried both split and length separately but not together . :)

Answer (score 2):

You were close with this:

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').split(",");
$('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays);
```

Should instead be this:

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').val().split(",").length;
$('#vacationDaysTaken').val(vacDays);
```

Comment: `.val` is a method. Missing `()`.

Answer (score 0):

Just count the array element that split() returns using the length property

```
var vacDays = $('#vacationDays').val().split(",");
var commaCount = vacDays.length;
```